# Spotify Syntax Error in vendor file when embedding Spotify podcast in iframe (IE11)

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, spotify

I have embedded a Spotify podcast in my iframe like so:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/episode/63nItp2YR57JYGM4EDPKWJ"></iframe>
```

This works fine on most browsers, except IE11. I do see the player, just pressing any button or link does nothing. I can see that no network calls are being done.
When I look into the console, I see a syntax error on a script that is loaded for this Spotify player (note: automatically, I have not added this script anywhere myself nor any npm packages):

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
vendor~embed-podcast.500107de.js (1, 76915)
```

It points towards a line in the script where it seems to have issues with the semicolon:

```
(...) (Oe||(Oe={}))); class ke extends Error (...)
```

I have looked for a polyfill or something to make IE work with this script, but to no avail yet. I can also find no one with this issue... What am I missing?
I have found information about Spotify not supporting IE but that had nothing to do with embedded stuff if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify webplayer is not supported in Internet explorer. ([Source](https://support.spotify.com/de/using_spotify/getting_started/webplayer/))

This is not something you could/should fix. I recommend you to just analyze the user agent and display a message if the user is using Internet Explorer.

Comment: I thought that the Web player was not the same functionality used when embedding in an iframe. But you say it is?

Comment: Yes, I assume embedding is some sort of "mini web player". Embedded throws a syntax error in IE which is why i think IE is not supported.